# Should I be linking to the home-page on completion of checkout?

Tags: navigation, workflow

I'm creating a design for an ecommerce website<sup>1</sup>, which includes the checkout/order process. One element that I'm concerned about in the design is the 'checkout completed' page, specifically **linking back to the home-page.**

I've reviewed a few ecommerce websites concerning this functionality (namely Amazon and eBay), and **they do not link back to the website's home-page at the end of the order process:**

[image]

In my design I've followed suit and have not included a 'Back to home', 'Continue shopping', or similar button:

[image]

Should I be including a 'continue shopping' button or similar?

<sup>1</sup><sup><sup>This is for a college assignment, so I won't be actually building it.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

This is because typically a customer does not continue shopping on the website after they place an order; they instead leave the website as there is nothing more to do (i.e, a 'continue shopping' button is not the expected workflow).

If appropiate, a link to **view/edit** the order can be used instead.

Comment: I second this. There is no need to take the user back to the home page. Instead, focus on the user's next steps. The most likely next step will be to view/edit the order or browse related content.